# Pop method of the certain element in a stack, Java

Tags: java, stack

So, i have this method pop(int k) where the whole point of the method is to pop the k value of the stack. So for example if k = 2 you pop the second element in the stack, this is a double linked stack so it should be possible to just iterate through it and pop() the element needed to be popped. However, for some reason when i run it the method has logical errors that i cant figure out.

```
public class DLStack<T> implements DLStackADT<T> {
    private DoubleLinkedNode<T> top;
    private int numItems;

    public DLStack(){
        top = null;
        numItems = 0;
    }

    public void push(T dataItem){
        DoubleLinkedNode<T> temp = new DoubleLinkedNode<T>(dataItem);
        temp.setNext(top);
        top = temp;
        numItems++;
    }

    public T pop() throws EmptyStackException{
        if(isEmpty())throw new EmptyStackException("Stack");
        T result = top.getElement();
        top = top.getNext();
        numItems--;
        return result;
    }

    public T pop(int k) throws InvalidItemException{
        DoubleLinkedNode<T> temp = top;
        if(k > numItems || k <= 0){
            throw new InvalidItemException("Invalid item");
        }

        for (int i = 1; temp != null && i < k; i++){
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }

        T result = temp.getElement();

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: The example could use more code, please provide a [mre]. Questions that are of interest before we can help you: What do you exactly mean by "pop in the stack"? Usually you can access a stack only from top to bottom (where top is the side you add new elements to and remove existing elements from). Should "pop"ing also modify the stack? In which way? What does the method `temp.getElement()` exactly do? Does it also modify the stack?

Comment: It's not a stak if you can pop a specific element, in a stack you can only pop the last added element (LIFO)

Comment: Your `pop(int)` method does not seem to remove the selected node (unlike a regular `pop()`). If that is intended, it might make sense to rename the method to `get(int)` or similar to avoid confusion. Would also be good to verify that all your methods update the references between the nodes correctly; if your stack is really doubly linked, then your `push(T)` and `pop()` methods might not correctly update all references between nodes. Your implementation looks more like a singly linked list.